# Show maximum theoretical wireless speed

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a GNU/Linux box acting as a wireless router. The wireless interface is in AP mode. It is actually an OpenWRT, but I guess it doesn't matter here.

I want to see the *theoretical* maximum transmit rate. Like when the advertisement says this router is capable of 802.11n 600 Mbps, I want to find somewhere to verify that indeed this wireless interface is capable of up to 600 Mbps. I understand that due to various reasons I might not get that speed in real action.

My intuition is: whether it's 450 Mbps or 600 Mbps, it's part of the 802.11n standard. There must be a way to list all supported standards for a physical device. I want to list supported 802.11 standards along with the speed limit.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm pretty sure no one ever implemented the 802.11n standard way to do 600Mbps (4 spatial streams), and the products that do 600Mbps in 2.4GHz do it in a nonstandard way (by using 802.11ac-style QAM-256 modulation in the 2.4GHz band).

Comment: @Spiff Thanks for the info. I guess this is listed in table in my answer below? I saw MCS index 23 can reach 600 Mbps using 256-QAM. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You read the chart wrong. N (HT) rates are in dark grey, with the left-hand HT MCS column. MCS 23 is 64-QAM, 3 stream, up to 450Mbps. AC (VHT) rates are light grey, right-hand VHT MCS column. Note also MCS 31 at 40MHz SGI.  These MCSes 24-31 were defined in the IEEE 802.11n standard, but I'm pretty sure no one ever shipped a radio that could do better than MCS 23.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks. So when you say 600 Mbps is implemented in ac style. I suppose it's implemented in the light grey area?

Comment: Yes. VHT MCS 9x3 (256-QAM 5/6 x 3 spatial streams), in a 40MHz channel with SGI, is the .11ac way of doing 600Mbps that some vendors do in 2.4GHz, even though that's going outside of the standard and sneaking a .11ac technique into the 2.4GHz band. The standard .11n way would have been HT MCS 31, which is 4 spatial streams, 64-QAM 5/6, 40MHz SGI.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question. After some Googling, I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/945517/how-to-determine-what-type-of-wifi-networks-are-supported-by-your-driver-on-linu). Basically, the `iw phy` command will show all information I need, but not straightforwardly.

I should look at `Capabilities` section. Mine says `HT20/HT40`, meaning it has 20 Mhz and 40 Mhz width support. Also there is `RX HT20 SGI` and `RX HT40 SGI`, meaning the data rate could reach `GI = 400 ns`. And mind the MCS rate indexes supported range from 0 to 23. Next I'd go to [mcsindex](http://mcsindex.com/) and lookup in the table. And the fastest theoretical speed would be 450 Mbps.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I was looking through my DD-WRT screen and came across these wireless terms. My main confusion is still around the SGI/GI terms - I have a few devices that are showing HT40, and others HT40 SGI.